# Error: You must import 'firebase/database' before using AngularFireDatabase

Tags: database, firebase, web, angular8, angularfire

Hello I am using angular 8 with angular fire, I have imported AngularFireModule and AngularFireDatabaseModule as well but when compiling it's throwing an error says:

Error:

[image]

These are my imports:

[image]

I am using firebase like this in services:

[image]

Please let me know where am I doing wrong or is it a bug.
Thanks

Comment: It would be great if you put the next time code in snippets, not just screenshots.

Comment: noted, next time will follow this pattern thanks, man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installing the angularfire package:

```
ng add @angular/fire@next
```

To be able to use realtime database in your code, you should import `firebase/database`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import 'firebase/database';
```

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md

Comment: Thanks, @peter-haddad it works. just imported firebase/database.